# What is the difference between erase and restore on Disk Utilily Mac?

Tags: macos, restore, hard-drive, fsck

Got a bit of vocabulary confusion. I want to re-format an external hard drive. But I'm not sure what the difference is between restore or erase.

Does erase, removes all files. or not.

I don't want to lose the files. But I'm in a position that can't allow me to back up the entire Volume, for lack of storage. SSDs are on the way, ETA 1 week.

I found this answer online but can't be sure of its correctness.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3111247?answerId=32268374022#32268374022

What I generally do to re-activate a hard drive that could be stuck on a task. Is the following on terminal:

`ps aux | grep fsck`

`sudo kill -9 [task number]`

but this solution does not format. or enable journaling. And, it limits the result by removing the drive's capability to re-write. Forcing me to apply:

**Disk Utility>First Aid** (so far, sometimes it takes long, others *very long*).

I feel like I'm asking many questions here.

**But I simply wish to know if erase or restore will enable journaling without losing all your data**

(if **Disk Utility** can do this from their GUI would be a lifesaver).

But I'm willing to learn other solutions in the terminal as to how I found out:

`ps aux | grep fsck`

Thanks in advance

Comment: To help you, you need to give us more information. Why do you want to modify this external disk? Is it an SSD or Hard drive? What Mac model, and OS version?

Answer (score 0):

**Erase** will delete all files. It erases the contents of the volume.

**Restore** in Disk Utility is to copy the contents of one disk, or disk image, onto another. This will also erase the previous contents.

However, it's not clear why you want to do this. **What is the problem that you are trying to solve?**

The Terminal commands that you provide do not 're-activate a hard drive that has got stuck on a task'. They kill a process that the CPU is running in memory. If you are trying to erase a disk and the process is becoming 'stuck', that might suggest a hardware problem on the disk itself.

You should never attempt any 'maintenance' or modification on a disk without a backup, as something could go wrong.